# Ruby on Rails - parameterize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to convert `ProductTypeId` to `product_type_id`.

`parameterize` function was not helpful.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @SebastianPalma, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```rb
ProductTypeId.to_s.underscore
```